# Sip/VoIP library for Java or c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, sip, voip

I am looking for a library (library for Java or C # or Vb.net) that will let me call a number through a VoIP service

I am interested in a really small library because I just need to call and hear the voice of the receiver using this data for call setup

```
SIP server (or proxy, or domain)    sip.sipserver.com
SIP proxy (or "Outbound Proxy")         leave blank
STUN server                         stun.sipserver.com
Username (or User ID)                   Myusername
Password                            Mypassword
Auth name (or Auth ID)                  Myusername
Display Name                            My name
Register (or Send registration request) Yes
G729a Codec Name (for buggy Linksys/Sipura/Cisco ATAs)  G729.
The default codec name in those adapters is set to non RFC compliant "G729a" and might not work with our service, go to Admin/Advanced/SIP menu in ATA settings to change the codec name.
Registry Expiry (or Registration interval)   120 sec (2 minutes) if your SIP client is behind NAT router.
```

If there isn't a library like that, or are too complex for my goal, maybe Java or C # have built something that allows me to hear the voice of the person I'm calling?

Comment: Provide a little more information on your application. What do you mean by "allows me to hear the voice of the person I'm calling." Do you want two way communications? Are you just trying to determine if there is a live person on the other end of the phone? Will it be an Interactive Voice Response (IVR) application that takes over once the phone is answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIP&RTP (sip + audio) libraries I know and I have been using are not really small, because there's a lot to do to write that library and it has to weight a bit. It depends what you consider as small size?

For .NET I would recommend:

- [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org) - Open source
- [Counterpath SDK](http://counterpath.com) It's commercial, not a cheap one for sure but really great. Jest mentioning - based on your post you don't need that capable library. Still - good to know that lib exists

With Java I've been using Peers: [link](http://peers.sourceforge.net/). It had some issues at the time but I don't think You would have to struggle with them. Your application wouldn't use those problematic parts of library.